# GNAT Programming Studio: New project location browser freezes after attempting to make a bookmark

Tags: gnat-gps

I just installed GPS on Windows 10

In order to make browsing to my source file folder less annoying, I tried adding it as a bookmark in the folder browser accessed from the new project window.

When I right clicked on the folder and added it as a bookmark, the window blanked and froze. Now, every time I open the folder browser, it blanks and freezes. I uninstalled and reinstalled GPS, but it didn't help.

I can open projects, since it uses the default windows folder browser, and I can create projects if I type the folder path manually.

How can I fix GPS to make the folder browser not freeze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue with help from Adacore customer support by removing the `AppData\local\gtk-3.0\bookmarks` file.